# If a set is a group of objects, then what is an object?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, philosophy

If a set is a group of objects, then what is an object?

My best try at this is the following:

An object is anything that we can discuss or think about,
separately from everything else. It is not necessarily a physical
object, it can also be an imaginary object such as a green elephant.

Once we have defined an object, then it makes sense to talk about
groups of objects, and this is where set theory begins.

Comment: In Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory _everything_ is a set. (I mean, everything that exists in the considered universe, because there are things we can imagine but which are not sets, such as the 'collection' of all sets.) I think the reason for this is that introducing a concept like 'object' would make the axoims unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: If you want to make sense of the question, you need to explain what a *group of objects* is.

Comment: @barto but that is the syntactic part of the theory. But what is the reason behind it?

Comment: I strongly disagree with your claim “this is where set theory begins”. The whole *point* of set theory is to deal with sets *without* having to worry about what the specific objects are or what their properties are; the whole point of set theory is to produce an *abstract* and *general* theory of collections and of membership in collections.

Comment: If a set is a collection of objects, then it's obvious what an object is --- it's the kind of thing that can be an element of a set.

Comment: I assume you don't mean the mathematical definition of "group."

Comment: Do you have a definition for 'anything' 'thinking' 'discussing' et cetera? At a certain point you must say something like: 'and now it's over, just accept this!' It is impossible to escape from mathematical 'things' that are *not* defined by means of other mathematical 'things'. Then you speak of a 'primitive thing'. Mostly sets are considered to be primitive in this sense.

Comment: @GitGud I refer to the intuitive notion of being able to separate things, and think of them as separate objects, and a group as a container of such objects, so that we can say each object belongs to that group. My point is, I don't want to enter philosophy, I want to take the intuitive meaning and move towards defining it mathematically.

Comment: @MJD Yes that is ok. We construct collections. But collections of what? This is where we must introduce the notion of an object.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I like that opinion, very nice. It goes in my notes ;)

Comment: No, we don't have to do that; the entire edifice of set theory refutes your silly claim.

Comment: @Nishant no no, not the mathematical group. A group in the everyday life sense, you have more things, you put them in a box and you have a group.

Comment: @MJD so basically you say, we don't have to define what an object is, and then we can go on and start grouping this objects into sets. Isn't that weird, a set is made of objects. So we construct something out of things we have not defined.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement

Comment: Before we have any "things" at a all, we have the empty set. And then we have the set containing the empty set. In order to describe set theory, though, we have to have a language - and where does the language come from? And where does the idea come from that this particular language, with this particular syntax and grammar, expresses something useful or beautiful - that this is a good language to use?

Comment: `My point is, I don't want to enter philosophy, I want to take the intuitive meaning and move towards defining it mathematically.` That's what the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ are for. Here, what you intuitively call an object, is also called a set. If you want to make a distinction between these, you can look at $\sf ZFU$, (Nishant posted alink above this above), or maybe [type theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) in which basically you can say that if, for example, $1,2,3$ and $9$ are objects of a certain order type, say type $n$, then $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1, 9\}$ are objects of type $n+1$.

Comment: You might like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764214/why-are-the-animals-in-a-field-a-set-why-is-a-group-a-set-what-does-qualify

Answer (score 2):

From Joseph Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568811357) (1967), page 238 :

> a set $A$ is formed by gathering together certain objects to form a single object, which is the set $A$. Thus before the set $A$ is formed, we must have available all of the objects which are to be members of $A$. [...]
>
> We are thus led to the following description of the construction of sets. We start with certain objects which are not sets and do not involve sets in their construction. We call these objects *urelements*. We then form sets in successive stages. At each stage we have available the urelements and the sets formed at earlier stages; and we form into sets all collections of these objects.
>
> > *A collection is to be a set only if it is formed at some stage in this construction* [emphasis added].
>
> We can carry out this construction with any collection of urelements. If we carry it out with no urelements, the sets which we obtain are called *pure* sets. It turns out that these are sufficient for mathematical purposes; and they are also sufficient to illustrate all the problems which arise in the general case.
>
> [Thus, in the "standard" treatment of set theory, like $\mathsf {ZF}$] we shall
> therefore restrict ourselves to this case, and henceforth take *set* or *class* to mean
> *pure set*.

Thus, if our choice is to have *urelements*, we can start with a collection of objects whatever: physical or abstract ones.

But if we start with physical objects, we are **not** licensed to assume the existence of *infinitely many* of them, while some sort of "axiom of infinity" is necessary for the development of "current" mathematics.